# pcap.net block or edit packets

Tags: c#, filter, block, winpcap, pcap.net

I want to manipulate a games roomlist, for filtering the maps.
My idea was, to filter the incoming packets for new rooms.

I can't find anything about how to edit or block incoming packets on the fly with pcap.net in c#.

is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pcap.net is a wrapper for WinPcap, it is *not* possible - libpcap/WinPcap can't block incoming packets, or modify them before they reach the networking stack, it can only passively capture packets and inject them.

Answer (score 3):

For packet editing/filtering you can try [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html).  The API is C so you'd need to write your own c# binding.

(disclosure: WinDivert is my project.)

Comment: can this running on OSx and linux ?

Comment: WinDivert is Windows only.  However, divert sockets (OSX) and `netfilter_queue` (Linux) provide similar functionality.